# AutoDock 4 -soft docking

Tags: proteins, software-usage, docking

How could I turn on/off the smooth potential in AutoDock4? I need to do two docking. The first one is soft docking with smooth potential and the second is re-docking without the smooth potential.

Answer (score 1):

The `smooth` parameter is an optional keyword and command that changes the smoothing potential. If not provided, the default is 0.5 angstroms by default. Try passing 0 with this keyword in the AutoGrid Parameter File to turn off smoothing potential.

See the [AutoDock 4.2.5 documentation](http://autodock.scripps.edu/faqs-help/manual/autodock-4-2-user-guide/AutoDock4.2_UserGuide.pdf) for more details.